# Make Default XIB File in Xcode 4.6 size of iPhone 4 Screen

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xib

Whenever I create a new class in Xcode 4.6 I get the tall XIB designed for the iPhone 5. I am not building an app for iPhone 5 and want to use Interface Builder to lay things out for the smaller screen. How do I change the default so that when new classes are created, I get the smaller XIB. Also, How do I change an existing iPhone 5 XIB into an iPhone 4 XIB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your XIB's attribute inspector there is a drop-down menu called "Simulated Metrics". In that change the size to "Retina 3.5 full screen". By doing this you can change the existing iPhone 5 sized XIB to iPhone 4 sized XIB